# How to skip a library crate's examples depending on the target platform?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a Rust library [crate](https://github.com/jugglerchris/rust-html2text) which I only use on Linux, but I don't know of any reason it shouldn't work on Windows; however one of the examples is Unix-specific, so it the crate fails the build on AppVeyor.

The reason is that there's a Unix-only dependency ([Termion](https://crates.io/crates/termion)) used by one of the examples, so when I used [an AppVeyor template](https://github.com/starkat99/appveyor-rust), it fails to build that dev-dependency.

So I made the dependency conditional:

```
[target.'cfg(unix)'.dev-dependencies]
termion = "1.0"
```

So far so good, but of course now that example fails on `extern crate termion`.

What I need is to just not build that example on non-Unix-like targets.  I was hoping something like:

```
[[target.'cfg(unix)'.example]]
name = "foo"
```

would work, but I get:

```
warning: unused manifest key: target.cfg(unix).example
error: no example target named `foo`
```

Another promising way forward was Cargo's [required-features](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-required-features-field-optional), but as of writing [it's apparently not in stable Cargo](https://github.com/tensorflow/rust/issues/64#issuecomment-284256802), which means that doesn't help me checking that it works on stable Rust on Windows.

The last option I can think of is to `#[cfg(unix)]` away most of the example's source, turning it into a stub on Windows, but I'd really like a cleaner way of doing it.

Is there some existing way of skipping an example on some unsupported targets that works with current stable Rust/Cargo?

Comment: I think `#![cfg(unix)]` away the example is cleanest...

Comment: @kennytm I was wondering that - but won't an "empty" file cause a compilation error?

Comment: @Shepmaster Hmm you're right. So that code needs to be additionally placed inside a `#[cfg] mod`, and `fn main()` forwards to the `mod`'s "main".

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by "*most* of the ... source" but in hindsight it wasn't crystal clear.  :-)